# Date of ROM installation

Tags: custom-roms

Is there any way to know when I flashed my last custom ROM?

Atleast a smart way to find the approximate date/time using some logs deep down in my android would be good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following in Terminal Emulator or ADB shell:

```
su
ls -l /system/
```

The date stamps on the read-only files/directories are the time they were created, i.e. approximately when the ROM was installed.

Comment: Great answer. There's no need to issue the cmd "su". I issued only the second line without root access and it worked great.

Comment: For me, this indicated 2009, which is certainly incorrect. Nexus 5.