# Android installation age

Tags: installation, system, date-and-time

Is there a way to discover when my Android OS was installed? In other word: what is the age of the SO running in my phone (since the last FW upgrade)?

I have root access and I prefer not installing any extra apps to this task (altough, if it is the only way, I may install one). I already have a Terminal Emulator App.

I looked into "Settings -> About phone" and there is a counter since the last *reboot*, which is **not** what I want.

I am running Android 4.0.4 on a Sony Xperia P.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how to know the last Android OS installation date. But if you logged in to your Google account at that day, you can search the log in date. Browse [there](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions), verify your phone model and check **authorization date**. Hope it works!

Comment: That date most likely is "refreshed" whenever you factory-reset your device. We had this topic already here, see e.g. [Date of ROM installation](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20503/16575) – which gets you closer to the real one :)

Comment: Oh. I didn't saw that topic in my search.

Anyway, that method didn't gave me accurate results.
`ls -l /system/` show a file (`omxloaders`) dated back from 2012, but I am absolutely sure that the last time I flashed this firmware was around just a year ago.

Comment: @Thiha method gave a more consistent date. I still think there must be a way to find this info more precisely on the device itself.